# undefined method `synchronize' in one to many model relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, one-to-many

I have a simple 1:n relationship in rails 4. Topics and Categories. Topic does have one category and category has many topics.

topic.rb

```
class Topic < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :category

end
```

category.rb

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :topics

end
```

I used the standard foreign key pattern so my topic model has an attribute

```
category_id
```

Now when doing some standard stuff I have the following issue:

This works fine when I list all topics that belong to a certain category:

```
<% @category.topics.each do |topic| %>
...
<% end %>
```

But doing this (simply show the category slug from the category that belongs to the topic):

```
<%= @topic.category.slug %>
```

plots this error:

```
undefined method `synchronize' for nil:NilClass
```

What do I do wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I think the source of your error is actually that you're referencing `@topic` when getting the category slug, but are passing the variable `topic` into your block, hence `@topic` is nil.

Comment: No, those two blocks are different from each other, sorry if that is not clear from my description.

`<%= @topic.category.slug %>` is referring to the instance variable

`@topic = Topic.find_by_id(params[:id])` and is def NOT nil because `<%= @topic.id %>` works for example.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was the friendly_id gem.
I had to use

```
gem 'friendly_id', '~> 5.0.0'
```

to work with rails 4.

Now it works perfectly.
Thanks to https://github.com/norman/friendly_id#what-changed-in-version-50